# SpringBoot 2.1.3 : Embedded Tomcat Logging

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, embedded-tomcat-8

I have developed a `SpringBoot 2.1.3` WebApp with `Thymeleaf 3`. For quick testing purpose I create a *fat jar* with two `SQL Procedure` which automatically create the DB if it is not present and fill typological table if they are empty.

Now I put my `.jar` in a **CentOS** server and launch it by the command:

```
java -jar mywebapp.jar
```

All works perfectly but I find a bug in a form submit and I would like to examine the server (embedded) logs.

Which `logging level` I have to use in the below configuration inside the `application.properties`:

```
logging.level.org.apache.tomcat=?
logging.level.org.apache.catalina=?
```

And where I can find the `log` text file inside a **Unix** machine?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all with embedded tomcat you have to enable log by adding to you `application.properties`

```
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=true
```

to specify base directory if you want to save log other then temp folder , also folder that will contain logs

```
server.tomcat.basedir=tomcat
server.tomcat.accesslog.directory=logs
```

you can also specify suffix and prefix  for logs file

```
server.tomcat.accesslog.suffix=.log
server.tomcat.accesslog.prefix=access_log
```

for more properties [see here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) list of common properties , search for tomcat and logging

Also adding logging level as mentioned by the PO in the comment add

```
logging.level.org.apache.tomcat=ALL
```

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly, for `logging level` I use `logging.level.org.apache.tomcat=ALL`

Comment: @CoderJammer  great , log lvl added to answer :)